# CipherClass exception in Decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

Decryption exception with CipherClass:
The encryption part works smoothly
The decryption throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:913)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)
    at rmihello.EncryptionModule.decryptText(EncryptionModule.java:23)
    at rmihello.Client.main(Client.java:56)
```

Here is my code:(which I call from a testclass, that has a secretKey and a message)

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class EncryptionModule {

    /**
     * Encrypts
     */
    public static String encryptText(String plainText, SecretKey key) throws Exception{
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] cipherT =  c.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        return new String(cipherT,"utf-8");
    }
    /**
     * Decrypts
     */
    public static String decryptText(String cipherText, SecretKey key) throws Exception{
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] clearT =  c.doFinal(cipherText.getBytes());
        return new String(clearT,"utf-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using ECB is not cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `String` to store bytes with a random value, and encryption should always return a result that is not distinguishable from random. Use base 64 (or for human consumption, hexadecimals) encoding instead.

For compatibility I would strongly recommend you to use a specific character set for the plaintext encoding (such as the UTF-8 as you are currently using).

Comment: I haven't misread anything. I've already indicated what you should do with the ciphertext.  You don't need another library you need to use another mode of operation for the cipher, as well as an IV. Sorry not behind my computer,  you'll need to invoke Google.

Comment: Sorry, I must have read your answer wrong, I made it work by parsing byte[] instead of Strings, just as you said. I also put in a base64. However, if I used the UTF-8, my strings would be misformatted (e.g. alexander -> alec/ander)